# What is the best Dotnet component suite?

Tags: .net

What do you feel is the best .net Component suite? There are a lot but what is the best one and why? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "best" according to you?

Comment: Do you mean UI Components? Componentes for Windows Forms, ASP, WPF?

Comment: yes component suite that support windows form + asp.net

Comment: Is this a request to all the component companies to plug in their sales ad?

Comment: No, I want to purchase component suite to use it in my projects, and I couldn't know what's the best one from the features that they provided, and I don't want to check all of them to decide.

Comment: In my opinion and according to my needs the best value/price one is [Nevron vision for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-vision.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/)

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)

[Component Factory](http://www.componentfactory.com/)

[DevComponents](http://www.devcomponents.com/)

[ASP.Net Control Gallery](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/)

[Dundas Chart](http://www.dundas.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want one or two to compare, is this the correct order?

Comment: In my opinion you can compare the top 3.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite subjective.

But Telerik is worth looking at. As us ComponentArt and DeveEx.

Best on is whatever works for you.

Comment: Programming is subjective.